# Change background of recyclerview item view without affecting other item's view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview which has 20 items. recyclerview holds thubnails of images. when an item is clicked, the image becomes visible in a viewpager.

when one swipe the viewpager, i get the position of the current item in the viewpager, i then get the view at that position in recyclerview and change it background **that is, to set the view with thubnail as selected**

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);


  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {

      recylerViewAdapter.changesBackground(position);
  }
```

**recyclerview adapter `changeBackgroundItem()`**

```
public void changesBackground(int position) {

    View v = recyclerView.getChildAt(position);
    if(v != null){
      v.setSelected(true);
    }

  }
```

**recyclerview row/item background resource**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Color when the row is selected -->
    <item  android:state_selected="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/md_red_A700" android:width="3dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/md_black_1000" android:width="2dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

The problem is that instead of only one item been selected, more than one item are becoming selected. e.g when i change background of item at position 1 to color red, items at position 8,10 e.tc also becomes selected.

- **Is this caused by recycling of items view?**
- **How can i avoid other items from being selected?**

Comment: If you select item at position 1 other random items change background color also?

Comment: @Tony i am not changing their backgrounds. are you suggesting that i change their backgrounds?

Comment: @Tony not working even when i do so

Comment: try changing `position` in `onBindViewHolder` to `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` so that you can get actual position in recycler view.

Comment: @harneev i had also tried that. but it was producing the same result as above.

Comment: @gikarasojokinene - after making changes to item you are calling `.notifyDataSetChanged();`. right ?

Comment: @harneev yes. am calling `.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @harneev see my answer below how i solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to solve the problem

Basically my issue was that if I scrolled away from the currently selected item in the recyclerView, due to recycling of the view,other item's view would also appear selected since i didn’t have a way to unselect the selected item when it was scrolled away. therefore multiple items would end up selected when you scroll through recyclerview.

I ended up getting this working using two interfaces. No ugly looping hacks required.

`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and `OnChildAttachStateListener`.

```
 public class MyActiviy extends AppCompatActivity implements
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener,RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener{

    int currentPosition = 0;
    int previousPosition = 0;
    ViewPager viewpager;
    RecyclerView recylerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    recylerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

    viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    recylerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(this);
   }

    @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    previousItemPos = currentItemPos;
    currentItemPos = position;

    clearSelectionBackground(previousItemPos);
    setSelectionBackground(currentItemPos);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

  }



     @Override
  public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
    //we have overide this method so that selected item
    //can remain selected when one scroll the recyclerview
    int childPosition = recylerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
    if (childPosition == currentItemPos) {
       //set selection
      view.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
     .getColor(android.R.color.RED));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {
    //remove selection
   view.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
   .getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

  }
  private void setSelectionBackground(int newItem) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = recylerView.findViewHolderForPosition(newItem);

    holder.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
   .getColor(android.R.color.RED));
  }

  private void clearSelectionBackground(int oldItem){

    if(oldItem != currentItemPos){
      RecyclerView.ViewHolder oldHolder = recylerView.findViewHolderForPosition(oldItem);

       oldHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
       .getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

    }
  }
   }
```